# Refactoring recurring ggplot code

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R and ggplot2 to analyze some statistics from basketball games. I'm new to R and ggplot, and I like the results I'm getting, given my limited experience. But as I go along, I find that my code gets repetitive; which I dislike.

I created several plots similar to this one:

[image: Net Rating by Effective Field Goal percentage]

Code:

```
efgPlot <- ggplot(gmStats, aes(EFGpct, Nrtg)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  geom_point(aes(colour=plg_ShortName, shape=plg_ShortName))  + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=as.numeric(gmStats$plg_ShortName))
```

Only difference between the plots is the x-value; next plot would be:

```
orPlot <- ggplot(gmStats, aes(ORpct, Nrtg)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm") + ...  # from here all is the same
```

How could I refactor this, such that I could do something like:

```
efgPlot <- getPlot(gmStats, EFGpct, Nrtg))
orPlot  <- getPlot(gmStats, ORpct, Nrtg))
```

*Update*

I think my way of refactoring this isn't really "R-ish" (or ggplot-ish if you will); based on baptiste's comment below, I solved this without refactoring anything into a function; see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862755/322283).

Comment: I would suggest that you `melt()` your dataset in long format, with `m = melt(gmStats, id="Nrtg")`. You can then either plot with `ggplot(m, aes(Nrtg, value)) + facet_wrap(~variable) + ...` or use `dlply(m, "variable", plottingFunction)` to create multiple plots.

Comment: Will try that too. For now I've accepted joran's answer, but this is a good suggestion for me to explore.

Comment: @baptiste - your melt + facet_wrap is a great solution, I've posted  the code I eventually used in [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862755/322283).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this sort of thing is using `aes_string` rather than `aes` (untested, of course):

```
getPlot <- function(data,xvar,yvar){
    p <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x = xvar, y = yvar)) + 
            stat_smooth(method = "lm") + 
            geom_point(aes(colour=plg_ShortName, shape=plg_ShortName))  + 
            scale_shape_manual(values=as.numeric(data$plg_ShortName))
    print(p)
    invisible(p)
}
```

`aes_string` allows you to pass variable names as strings, rather than expressions, which is more convenient when writing functions. Of course, you may not want to hard code to color and shape scales, in which case you could use `aes_string` again for those.

Comment: I had to to do `aes_string(x = xvar, y = yvar)` instead of `aes_string(xvar, yvar)`; but I think I get it now. I corrected your answer. Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Although Joran's answer helpt me a lot (and he accurately answers my question), I eventually solved this according to baptiste's suggestion:

```
# get the variablesI need from the stats data frame:
forPlot <- gmStats[c("wed_ID","Nrtg","EFGpct","ORpct","TOpct","FTTpct",
                     "plg_ShortName","Home")] 
# melt to long format:
forPlot.m <- melt(forPlot, id=c("wed_ID", "plg_ShortName", "Home","Nrtg"))
# use fact wrap to create 4 plots:
p <- ggplot(forPlot.m, aes(value, Nrtg)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=plg_ShortName, colour=plg_ShortName)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=as.numeric(forPlot.m$plg_ShortName)) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm") +
  facet_wrap(~variable,scales="free")
```

Which gives me:

[image: Net rating as function of four performance indicators]